# Is there some memory leak in Mint 16? Or else what is this?

Tags: linux-mint, memory-leaks

So this has happened to me 3 times now: I have left my computer on over night and when I come back in the morning all of my ram is being used and about a third to a half of my swap space is full.

Here's some information that may or may not be pertinent:

- I have 7.8GiB ram and 8GiB swap.
- I am running Linux Mint Petra with cinnamon 2.
- When I look at system monitor while this is happening no process is
  using an inordinate of memory and all 8 cores of my CPU are running sub 10%
- Aside from my start-up applications, the only thing I have running
  overnight is firefox idling on my open tabs. I have only added Guake
  and Cairo Dock to my start-up apps in addition to the default Mint
  start-up applications.
- I have installed jack and therefore some of my memory limits may
  have been changed. This is the output from `ulimit -a`:

  ```
  core file size          (blocks, -c) 0 
  data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
  scheduling priority             (-e) 0
  file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
  pending signals                 (-i) 61806
  max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
  max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
  open files                      (-n) 1024
  pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
  POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
  real-time priority              (-r) 0
  stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
  cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
  max user processes              (-u) 61806
  virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
  file locks                      (-x) unlimited
  ```

  (I think that I had not installed jack the first time this happened, though I am not positive)
- I have done some anti-virus things including, but not limited to, completely reinstalling my system between incident 2 and 3. Also incident 3 came on night 2 after reinstall. All anti-virus things seem to indicate that my computer is clean.
- I had to leave in the middle of writing this question. I was gone for 12 hours. Aside from my start-up apps, firefox, system monitor, and my Downloads folder were still open: my memory usage has gone from about 1.1-1.2 Gib when I left to 1.6 GiB now.

So my questions are: (a) Is this indicative of a memory leak? I don't quite know what a memory leak looks like. (b) If yes, how do I ferret out the culprit? (c) If no, is there anything else I could start looking at?